# Function is working when assigned to a variable but throwing SyntaxError when executed by itself

Tags: javascript

I had an IIFE like this one:

```
(function a() {
    return "b";
}());
```

Executed in the console, it returns `"b"`.

I removed the first set of parentheses, thinking that this'll make the "a" function global, but still work, and return `"b"`:

```
function a() {
   return "b";
}();
```

But it throws a `SyntaxError`:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
```

Then, I tried converting the function to an expression by assigning to a variable, and it worked:

```
var c = function a() {
   return "b";
}();
console.log(c); // prints b
```

Why does this happen? Why is it working as an expression but not by itself?

Comment: What do you think the result of `function a() {
   return b;
}();` would be if it did work??

Comment: @epascarello Good catch. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 4):

The second piece of code is not what it looks like.

This code looks like a function that is being immediately executed:

```
function a() {
    return "b";
}()
```

But in reality, it's just a function declaration followed by an empty expression, which is not allowed:

```
function a() {
    return "b";
}

() // not allowed - empty expression
```

Ben Alman explains this in his [article](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) on IIFE's:

> When the parser encounters the `function` keyword in the global scope or
>   inside a function, it treats it as a function declaration (statement),
>   and not as a function expression, by default.
>
> ...
>
> While parens placed after an expression indicate that the expression
>   is a function to be invoked, parens placed after a statement are
>   totally separate from the preceding statment, and are simply a
>   grouping operator (used as a means to control precedence of
>   evaluation).

The grouping operator needs to contain an expression to evaluate. By itself it's of no meaning:

```
() // meaningless
2 + 3 * 4 // 15
(2 + 3) * 4 // 20
```

In IIFE's, the outer parentheses are just a means of forcing the parser to expect an expression.

This is why the expression `var c = function() { return "b"; }();` also works; it's because the parser knows to expect an expression because of the assignment to `c`.

**Side Note**

Alman also recommends against using self-invoking functions without using the outer parentheses when assigning to variables(i.e. `var v = function(){...}()`) because it's bad practice:

> In cases where the extra “disambiguation” parens surrounding the
>   function expression are unnecessary (because the parser already
>   expects an expression), it’s still a good idea to use them when making
>   an assignment, *as a matter of convention.*
>
> Such parens typically indicate that the function expression will be
>   immediately invoked, and the variable will contain the *result* of the
>   function, not the function itself. This can save someone reading your
>   code the trouble of having to scroll down to the bottom of what might
>   be a very long function expression to see if it has been invoked or
>   not.